# LWUIT display bold text + normal text

Tags: java-me, lwuit, text-formatting

I need to display some Rich-Text in LWUIT.

I was thinking of HTML Component, but I can't get linewrapping there - probably an error on my side.

Another idea would be to use TextAreas or Labels and do it manually.

I'd need the possibility to have bold words in a non bold sentence.

**Hello**, this is a **bold**. <- This dot shouldn't be **bold**.

Is there a way I can achieve that? I think I only can use one Font per Component...

Comment: Perhaps several Labels with modified margin+padding+flowlayout would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Container with flow layout and just place labels into it. This is what the HTML Component does internally.

Comment: I'd like to do that, but unfortunately this would require manually linebreaking, if I'm not mistaken, something I'd not like to do, since I'll face many many different languages.

Comment: Nope. FlowLayout breaks lines automatically.

Comment: Form f = new Form();
       FlowLayout exampleLayout = new FlowLayout();
       f.setLayout(exampleLayout);
       f.addComponent(new Label("I am a Laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabel"));
       f.show();


Shows me Laaaaaaaaaa... instead of line wrapping. My error?

Comment: A single long word won't break a line however if you break your sentence into multiple labels it will wrap automatically (that's what HTML component does internally).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now. But that's what I didn't want to code myself, since I'm afraid of problems arising with some languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try **com.sun.lwuit.html.HTMLComponent** class. Use it like,

```
HTMLComponent htmlComp = new HTMLComponent(null);
htmlComp.setBodyText("<b>Hello</b>, this is a <b>bold</b>. &lt;- This dot shouldn't be <b>bold</b>.");
form.addComponent(htmlComp);
```

This component will allow you to use html tags inside text. For more information, refer this link: [HTMLComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/bbjidhgf.html)

Comment: I was thinking of HTML Component, but I can't get linewrapping there - probably an error on my side.